# ¿Como obtener el registro con fecha mas cercana a la actual en sqlite?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, sqlite

mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que en una consulta de sqlite aparesca el registro con la fecha mas cercana a la actual, solo uno, trato de llenar un recyclerView pero solo debe de aparecer los datos que tengan la fecha mas cercana, asi es mi metodo para mostrar los datos:

```
private List<RegistroAuto> ObtenerLista() {
    SQLiteHelper base = new SQLiteHelper(getContext(),"Cartago.db",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase datos = base.getReadableDatabase();
    List<RegistroAuto>lista= new ArrayList<>();
    RegistroAuto registroAuto = null;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    String fecha = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    Cursor cursor = datos.rawQuery("SELECT Marca,Placa,FecSoap,Modelo FROM tbl_regautosx",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        registroAuto = new  RegistroAuto();
        registroAuto.setMarca(cursor.getString(0));
        registroAuto.setPlaca(cursor.getString(1));
        registroAuto.setFecSoap(cursor.getString(2));
        registroAuto.setModelo(cursor.getString(3));
        lista.add(registroAuto);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

funciona pero debe aparecer solo aquel cuya fecha de vencimiento de soat sea mas cercana (FecSoap), como puedo hacerlo, como planteo la consulta o como las comparo, de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porqué no lo haces en la consulta de una?

```
SELECT * FROM laTabla
WHERE  date(campoFecha) <= date(laFecha) 
ORDER BY date(campoFecha)
DESC Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `query` en lugar de `rawquery`:

```
 String[] columnas = new String[] {"Marca", "Placa", "FecSoap", "Modelo"};
 Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_regautosx", columnas, null, null, null, null, FecSoap+" DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Los parámetros del query son:

```
TableName, columns, where, args, group, having, order by.
```

Por lo tanto el último parámetro es el de ordenar, en este caso en base a la columna de
fechas, de forma descendente (de mas cercas a más lejos) y mostrando solo un resultado (`LIMIT 1`).
Si quieres que se muestren todos los resultados solo agrega `" DESC"`
Respetar el espacio antes de DESC (`" DESC ...`).