# Como mostrar solo 3 items

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo el siguiente código que es un array en php

```
<?php
    $conexion=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
        or die("No se pudo conectar la base de datos");
    mysql_select_db($db,$conexion)
        or die ("No se encontro los resultados");
    $query ="SELECT * FROM noticias";
    $resultado = mysql_query($query);
    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){ 
        echo "$fila[titulo]";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Con LIMIT directo en tu consulta SQL. La cual por cierto deberías colocar

Comment: Agrega tu consulta SQL desde ahí se puede hacer lo que buscas

Comment: $query ="SELECT * FROM noticias LIMIT 3"; Te refieres a esto?

Comment: Si, es la que estás usando?

Comment: Si estoy usando pero me falta el Limit...dejame agregar un titulo más a ver si funciona, pero como hago para que sean los tres ultimos?

Comment: Investiga sobre orden by combinado con desc y el uso de limit y con eso lo tendrás hecho

Comment: con un order by podes filtrar los 3 últimos o 3 primeros

Comment: Si sólo necesitas tres filas, deberías usar `LIMIT 3` (si usas MySQL, que tampoco lo dices). Y para el orden, puedes usar `ORDER BY`, por ejemplo, para orden `DESC`endente: `SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY laColumnaPorLaQueQuieresOrdenar DESC LIMIT 3` y para orden `ASC`endente cambias `DESC` por `ASC` en la consulta. Por supuesto, debes cambiar `laColumnaPorLaQueQuieresOrdenar` por el nombre de tu columna real.

Comment: un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/195240/81450

Comment: @KarlosYalta vete modificando la pregunta con las instrucciones que te van dando los compañeros (muy importante el SQL), así podrán enviarte la respuesta que necesitas. Ánimo que ya casi lo tienes.

Comment: Ahora usas MySQL?

Comment: Ya veo que usas `LIMIT`, ahora una pregunta: **¿funciona, muestra algo?** Para el orden puedes usar `ORDER BY  columna  ASC` o bien `ORDER BY  columna  DESC` donde `ASC` significa *ascendente*  y `DESC` *descendente*. Otra cosa que veo mal es esta: `echo "$fila[titulo]";`, debería ser: `echo $fila["titulo"];`, y si usas PHP 7, el código no funcionará, porque la extensión `mysql_*` fue sacada del core de PHP. Deberás pasar a mysqli o a PDO.

Comment: Lo he estado usando ..solo que no vi necesario pegarlo porque la pregunta consideraba que era algo directa

Comment: Te falta indicar si será ASC o DESC para encontrar los resultados que buscas

Comment: No es válido que coloques la respuesta en tu pregunta

Comment: En todo caso publica la respuesta y explica que hiciste

Comment: Karlos, ten en cuenta que este sitio no funciona como los foros. La intención es aportar respuestas de calidad en las preguntas, donde se pueda aprender. No es cuestión de resolver algo y fulminarlo diciendo: `RESUELTO`. En este caso, una respuesta de calidad explicaría la solución y cómo funcionan ciertas cosas como `LIMIT` y `ORDER BY`, haciendo referencia a la documentación por ejemplo. Este sitio existe para dos cosas: para ayudar a los programadores a resolver sus problemas y para que otros aprendan de esas preguntas/respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok esto es lo que hice para resolverlo gracias a todas sus aportaciones:

1. Coloque en la base de datos una columna con el nombre de indice y le di la propiedad auto_increment (INT).
2. Coloque en la consulta ORDER BY indice DESC
   *Esto para que me mostrara la lista en forma descendente.*
3. Coloque la propiedad LIMIT 
   *para especificar cuantos títulos quería que se muestren*

Y este es el código final...

```
<?php
    $conexion=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
        or die("No se pudo conectar la BD");
    mysql_select_db($db,$conexion)
        or die ("No se encontro los resultados");
    $query ="SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY indice LIMIT 3";
    $resultado = mysql_query($query);
    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){ 
        echo "$fila[titulo]";
    }
?>
```

Gracias son unos capos!